# Reset keith-wood Countdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the keith-wood Countdown in the following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: +60,
        format: 'yodhmS',
        layout: '{y<}{yn}a, {y>}{o<}{on}m, {o>}{d<}{dn}g, {d>}{h<}{hn}o, {h>}{m<}{mn}m, {m>}{s<}{snn}s{s>}'
    });
});
```

I want to reset the countdown when the user clicks Reset button. I've tried the following solution but it doesn't work. I get the following error: "Uncaught Unknown command: change"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('change', {until: +60});
    });
});
</script>

<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use `change` (this is not defined. Use `option` instead:

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('option', { until: +60 });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

'change' should be 'option', which will restart the counter at 60 seconds when the reset button is clicked:

```
$('#reset').click(function() {
   $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('option', {until: +60});
});
```

In full:

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: +60,
        format: 'yodhmS',
        layout: '{y<}{yn}a, {y>}{o<}{on}m, {o>}{d<}{dn}g, {d>}{h<}{hn}o, {h>}{m<}{mn}m, {m>}{s<}{snn}s{s>}'
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('option', {until: +60});
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for duplicating - Mark's solution appeared as I posted mine.